# Video broadcast with Android's Camera2 API

Tags: android, broadcast, camera2

I'm trying to make an app which broadcast video through internet, currently I am using the deprecated Camera API, adding a Camera.PreviewCallback to the Camera object and then sending the byte array which comes in the onPreviewFrame() method from Camera.PreviewCallback.

But now I want to test the new Camera2 API, I am watching at the [Camera2BasicTutorial](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) , and I think that I need to make a CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback object to get the image byte array, something like the tutorial says:

```
CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                           @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                           @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                showToast("Saved: " + mFile);
                Log.d(TAG, mFile.toString());
                unlockFocus();


            }
        };
```

And then add it to the CameraCaptureSession:

```
mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve each image byte array from any of the parameters in onCaptureCompleted() from the CaptureCallback.

Any help?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/averagelosercom/android/android-camera-api-v2-preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I realized how to do what I wanted, from the [Camera2BasicTutorial](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic), I did the following changes to the Camera2BasicFragment class:

1. Modify captureStillPicture() method to delete stuff which I determined that was unneccessary with my broadcast needs, also don't allow this method to stop the repeating mode:

   ```
   private void captureStillPicture() {
   try {
       final Activity activity = getActivity();
       if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {
           return;
       }

       final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
               mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
       captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

       CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
               = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

           @Override
           public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                          @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                          @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
           }
       };

       mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
   } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   ```
2. In createCameraPreviewSession() method, disable the automaticall flash:

   ```
   // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                       mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                       try {
                           // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                           mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                   CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                           // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
   // mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
   // CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);

                           // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                           mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                           mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                   mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                       } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
   ```
3. I created a boolean var to detect if there is an image currently being under process, to not queue all the frames that the camera captures; and another boolean to track if there is a frame sending through internet:

   ```
   private boolean mWorking = false;
   private boolean mNetworkWorking = false;
   ```
4. Modify the CaptureCallback object to run the captureStillPicture() method in each frame (only if there is no frame processing at the moment).

   ```
               case STATE_PREVIEW: {

               if (!mWorking){
                   Log.d(TAG, "capturing..");
                   mWorking = true;

                   mBackgroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           captureStillPicture();
                       }
                   });

               } else {
                   Log.d(TAG, "thread working, doing nothing");
               }


               break;
   ```
5. Finally, read the frame and send it; I achieved this modifying the OnImageAvailableListener object:

   ```
   private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
       = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

   @Override
   public void onImageAvailable(final ImageReader reader) {

       // Process the image.
       Image image = reader.acquireNextImage();
       ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
       final byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
       buffer.get(bytes);
       image.close();

       if (!mNetworkWorking){
           Thread thread = new Thread(){
               @Override
               public void run(){

                   mNetworkWorking = true;

                   HttpResponse response = null;
                   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                   HttpPost post = new HttpPost(mBroadcastUrl);
                   post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(bytes));

                   try {
                       response = client.execute(post);
                   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                       if (BuildConfig.LOCAL_LOG)
                           Log.w(TAG, "ClientProtocolException: "+e.getMessage());
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       if (BuildConfig.LOCAL_LOG)
                           Log.w(TAG, "IOException: "+e.getMessage());
                   }

                   mNetworkWorking = false;

               }
           };

           thread.setName("networkThread");
           thread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
           thread.start();
       }

       mWorking = false;

   }

   };
   ```

That's all.

Comment: I tried your code but it calls onImageAvailable 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of right- you can't get the image data from the `onCaptureCompleted()` method. That callback only returns the metadata about the exposure for your own bookkeeping. The actual image information gets sent to whatever `Surface` you indicated in the exposure's `CaptureRequest`.

Comment: This is not a specific code issue, but rather an understanding of the basic framework/system of camera2. It is best outlined here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html
When it comes to an actual Surface where the image data will appear, you will probably want to use the Surface of a MediaCodec or MediaRecorder, and I am unfamiliar with those and so cannot provide code examples.